# Searching with multiple inputs in android

Tags: android, sql, search

What is the right way to get multiple user inputs in android? So basically something like [this](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/multiinput/), and then use those inputs to find related data on the database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use android [searchView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog) and [chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) concept.